# Hanson-Wright Inequality for Symmetric Matrices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The Hanson-Wright inequality for arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix A, and $X$ a random vector with subgaussian coordinates (of norm 1) is
$$
Pr(|X^TAX-\mathbb{E}X^TAX| \geq t) \leq 2\exp \left(-c \min\left(\frac{t^2}{\|A\|_F}, \frac{t}{\|A\|} \right)\right)
$$

A proof of this follows first by decoupling and showing that equivalently we may consider 
$$
Pr(|X^TAX' - \mathbb{E}X^TAX'| \geq t)
$$
for i.i.d. $X,X'$. We then establish in the case where $X,X'$ are gaussian the bound 
$$
\mathbb{E}\exp(\lambda X^TAX') \leq \exp(C\lambda^2\|A\|_F^2)
$$
Finally, one shows that we can replace arbitrary $X,X'$ with normally distributed counterparts while only paying a constant cost (see page 140 of Vershynin High Dimensional Probability). In particular, for $X,X'$ with subgaussian entries of norm 1, and with $g,g' \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$, we have the bound 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\exp(\lambda X^TAX') \leq\mathbb{E}\exp(C\lambda g^TAg') 
\end{equation}
for some constant $C$.

I'm interested in the case where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. When $X$ are gaussian, we can already assume that $A$ in $X^TAX$ is diagonal. Crucially (or so it seems to me), we don't need to decouple here. This lets one bound the moment generating function of $X^TAX$ like
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\exp(\lambda X^TAX) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} \exp(\lambda a_iX_i^2)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2\lambda a_i)^{-1/2} \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \exp(2\lambda a_i)
\end{align*}
if $\lambda < \frac{1}{4}$, using the identity $(1-t)^{-1/2} < e^{t}$ for $t < 1/2$. So one can replace $\|A\|_F$ with $tr(A)$, which should give a better bound.

If we want to get this result in general though, we need some result along the lines of 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\exp(\lambda X^TAX) \leq\mathbb{E}\exp(C\lambda g^TAg) 
\end{equation}
Does such a bound hold?

(I am sourcing this material from chapter 6 of Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability)

Comment: When $A$ is PSD, one can write $A=BB^T$ and observe that $\mathbb{E}_X\exp(\lambda X^TAX) = \mathbb{E}_X\exp(\lambda \|BX\|_2^2)  = \mathbb{E}_X\mathbb{E}_g\exp(\sqrt{\lambda} \langle BX,g\rangle)  = \mathbb{E}_g\mathbb{E}_X \exp(\sqrt{\lambda} \langle X,B^Tg\rangle) \leq  \mathbb{E}_g\exp(C\lambda \|B^Tg\|_2^2\rangle) = \mathbb{E} \exp(C\lambda g^T BB^T g)$ 

and you can proceed similarly as before, noting that the nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ and those of $BB^T$ are the same.